# jQuery sortable drag and drop - cloning and other issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I'd like to begin with saying what I'm trying to do. I'm currently working on a menu generator (idk how to name it exactly), something like placing widgets in WordPress but for creating menu on a website. I've tried to do it using jQuery and Sortable (I've tried Draggable and LiveQuery too but that's not what I'm looking for) but I have some problems:

- the user should be given the possibility of hiding the content of the item but the button hiding/unhiding it blocks after copying the item
- the source item should be cloned and not moved (but using a placeholder - I couldn't find draggable with a placeholder) without being removed from list (I have a temporary solution with adding the source item on the end of list but that isn't what I want to achieve)
- the item has to be moved from one column to another (i.e. from #column1 to #column2, not #column1 -> #column1 [same with #column2] and not #column2 -> #column1)

Here's the code:

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
$('.dragbox').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.dragbox-content').css('display', 'none');
});
$('.dragbox')
.each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).find('h2').addClass('collapse');
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('h2').removeClass('collapse');
    })
    .find('h2').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.configure').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('.configure').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    })
    .click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.dragbox-content').toggle();
    })
    .end()
    .find('.configure').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
$('.column').sortable({
    connectWith: '.column',
    handle: 'h2',
    cursor: 'move',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    opacity: 0.4,
    stop: function(event, ui){
        if (ui.target == event.target) alert("Error!");
        $(ui.item).find('h2').click();
        $(ui.item).clone().appendTo(event.target);
        $(event.target).each(function(){
            $(this).find('.dragbox-content').css('display', 'none');
        });
    },
    remove: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.target == event.target) alert("Error!");
    }

});
});
```

and HTML:

```
<h3>Drag n Drop - menu test</h3>

<div class="column" id="column1">
    <div class="dragbox" id="item1" >
        <h2>category</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" >
            Name: <input type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragbox" id="item2" >
        <h2>button</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" >
            Text: <input type="text"/><br />
            Link: <input type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragbox" id="item3" >
        <h2>html code</h2>
        <div class="dragbox-content" >
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column" style="width: 49%;" id="column2" >
</div>
```

I know it may look chaotic so there's an example of what I mean:
http://hun7er.pl/poligon/dragndrop/
The code is based on that tutorial: http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/collpasible-drag-drop-panels/

As you can probably see only content of the target item can be hidden/unhidden and sometimes while trying to hide/unhide the item can be accidentally cloned. I've searched for a solution here, on stackoverflow, and in some other places (Google search) but nearly all solutions concern Draggable or LiveQuery and I have no idea how to use a placeholder there (as I mentioned I couldn't find any tutorial/thread/post with draggable&placeholder).

I've thought about using regexp to change item id (it stays the same for all cloned items) but idk how to get item id and changind it using Firebug doesn't seem to help.
Sorry if there was a similar thread but I couldn't find any (the only one I can see now has no solution).

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer what I think is your most pressing question, here is an example of the jQueryUI sortable using a [placeholder](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#placeholder).

However, I think what you might be after is actually the [**helper**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-helper) property, which is used to define an element to be displayed while dragging.

Regarding your explicit questions (I've prepended a classifier to help identify what I perceive to be the problem) ...

> **Event Binding Problems**: the user should be given the possibility of hiding the content of the item but the button hiding/unhiding it blocks after copying the item.

To address this problem you'll need to use event delegation, ideally scoping the event delegation to your columns for performance reasons. jQuery has a [.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method which allow you to achieve this. Here's some sample code based on your markup:

```
$('.column').delegate('.dragbox h2', 'hover', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('collapse');
});

$('.column').delegate('.dragbox', 'click', function() {
    $(this).find('.dragbox-content').toggle();
});
```

What this allows you to do is not worry about re-binding events when you generate your elements, as per the description in the jQuery docs on .delegate: "*Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, **now or in the future**, based on a specific set of root elements.*"

> **Cloning** : the source item should be cloned and not moved (but using a placeholder - I couldn't find draggable with a placeholder) without being removed from list (I have a temporary solution with adding the source item on the end of list but that isn't what I want to achieve)

In order to properly clone the item I might suggest changing your interface paradigm so you have a button that instructs the user with a call to action like "Click to Add" or something like that. It would be better to have a button that drove adding instead of worrying about drag drop. You can still do .sortable within column2 but having a button would simplify the add interaction.

> **Drop Restrictions** : the item has to be moved from one column to another (i.e. from #column1 to #column2, not #column1 -> #column1 [same with #column2] and not #column2 -> #column1)

If you go with a button paradigm for the adding then you can avoid needing to worry about these restrictions. Also, take a look at the [receive function](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-receive) as it might provide more ability to restrict and revert should you not want to go with the button paradigm.